# Can I change or replace Unity Launcher Dash behavior?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

Recently I installed `Synapse` launcher and I use it as default one now as due to my reasons of RAM memory lack `Synapse` works twice faster. What I'd like to know if it's possible to change or replace Unity Launcher Dash behavior as when I click on Ubuntu logo (Dash) in Unity Launcher so it opens `Synapse` search engine instead of default?

Comment: I'd doubt it, you could have more luck using another desktop enviroment if you lack RAM and don't want or can't buy more.

Comment: good notice maybe I need to get more RAM but still maybe somebody knows something else.

Comment: Following @xangua's advice decided to switch to xfce, configured it to my needs and everything works fine now, so I voted to close it as it doesn't bother me anymore. Though maybe somebody in the future will be interested in the same so decided not to delete it.

Comment: I would still leave an answer instead of closing it and leaving a comment.  That would mean the question will be deleted automatically by the system sometime in the near future, whereas an answered question will help someone in the future....  @xangua:  would you like to do the honours???

Comment: I  agree probably if @xangua write some answer I'll take it for consideration to accept it. ;)